# Phase Lines Equilibrium Points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have du/dt = f(u), and suppose f(u) has two equilibrium points. a and b

I'm pretty sure I know the definition of a stable equilibrium point, it would be in the case of a phase line, both arrows would be facing the equilibrium point. So if a was stable both arrows would be facing towards a. And the same is true for an unstable equilibrium point, except both arrows would be facing away from a.

However, is there a term for when one is facing away from a and the other is facing towards a? I.e. let's say if u < a then the arrow faces towards a, and if a < u < b then the arrow faces away from a. Is the equilibrium point stable? Unstable? Or a separate name altogether?